# httr::GET() can't be handled purrr::safely()?

Tags: r, httr, purrr

This is probably a fundamental misunderstanding on my part, but I thought `purrr::safely()` captured all errors and never failed. Yet:

```
> purrr::safely(httr::GET('http://revolution-news.com/'))
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`safely` is a function wrapper, not a function call wrapper. Use

```
purrr::safely(httr::GET)('http://revolution-news.com/')
```

Notice how it wraps the function `GET()`, not the call to get. You could break that apart to

```
safe_GET <- purrr::safely(httr::GET)
safe_GET('http://revolution-news.com/')
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's it. Thanks!